# show engine= inno db status; found the deadlock and blokcing txn_id need to find the blocking query

Tags: mysql, locking

```
             trx_id: 19257543100
             trx_state: RUNNING
             trx_started: 2023-07-19 14:59:14
             trx_requested_lock_id: NULL
             trx_wait_started: NULL
             trx_weight: 15
             trx_mysql_thread_id: 18302796
             trx_query: NULL
             trx_operation_state: NULL
            trx_tables_in_use: 0
             trx_tables_locked: 1
            trx_lock_structs: 11
            trx_lock_memory_bytes: 1128
            trx_rows_locked: 11
            trx_rows_modified: 4
         trx_concurrency_tickets: 0
   trx_isolation_level: REPEATABLE READ
     trx_unique_checks: 1
trx_foreign_key_checks: 1
```

trx_last_foreign_key_error: NULL
trx_is_read_only: 0
trx_autocommit_non_locking: 0

this is my blocking txn_id why teh txn_query:Null how to find the related query.is there any script to get teh "Null"query.Please let me know

Comment: Would you please take the time to format it.  I am not upvoting a mess

Comment: `SHOW ENGINE=InnoDB STATUS;`

Comment: It should have listed the two competing queries.  Let's set them.